How to define a generalisation to_string and to_wstring to avoid code duplication
I have a number of user-defined classes for which I would like to define a to_string function. However, instead of defining this for just std::string, I would like to define this for all the possible instantiations of std::basic_string. So, here follows a naive attempt at this, that falls short:
We have some types, and we define to_basic_string() functions for each of them. Then we have the more specific to_string(), to_wstring(), to_u8string(), which wraps around the to_basic_string() for each of the basic_string instantiations. A generic arg is used so we don't have to define the same thing for each and every user-defined type.
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std::literals;

// Define the types...

template <std::size_t... Is>
struct foo {};

struct bar {};

struct baz {};

// ...


// Define the generic to_basic_string functions...

template<typename char_type, std::size_t first, std::size_t... Is>
std::basic_string<char_type> to_basic_string(foo<first, Is...> arg)
{
    std::basic_stringstream<char_type> stst;

    stst << "foo<"s << first;

    if (sizeof...(Is) > 0)
    {
        ((stst << ","s << Is), ...);
    }

    stst << ">"s;

    return stst.str();
}

template<typename char_type>
std::basic_string<char_type> to_basic_string(bar arg)
{
    using namespace std::literals;

    return "bar"s;
}

template<typename char_type>
std::basic_string<char_type> to_basic_string(baz arg)
{
    using namespace std::literals;

    return std::basic_string<char_type>{};
}

// ...


// Define (for generic argument) functions that convert to the particular basic_string instantiations, such as string, wstring, etc.

std::string to_string(auto arg)
{
    return to_basic_string<char>(arg);
}

std::wstring to_wstring(auto arg)
{
    return to_basic_string<wchar_t>(arg);
}

std::u8string to_u8string(auto arg)
{
    return to_basic_string<char8_t>(arg);
}

// ...

int main()
{
    std::cout << to_string(foo<0, 2, 4, 6, 8>{}) << "\n"s;
    std::cout << to_string(bar{}) << "\n"s;
    std::cout << to_string(baz{}) << "\n"s;

//  std::wcout << to_wstring(foo<0, 2, 4, 6, 8>{}) << L"\n"s;
//  std::wcout << to_wstring(bar{}) << L"\n"s;
//  std::wcout << to_wstring(baz{}) << L"\n"s;
}

When using this for to_string(), things appear to work fine. For to_wstring() and the others, it fails to compile, and this isn't too surprising: the to_basic_string() functions all make use of basic_string literals like "foo<"s that are only applicable to char-based literals.
This raises the question: how do I get this function to support the various basic_string types without having to effectively duplicate the function logic? Note the provided functions have fairly straightforward implementations due to being minimal examples, and thus do not reflect their actual counterparts. However, they do reflect the general elements involves: string literals are used throughout, and stringstreams are used to concatenate elements.
As for choice of c++ standard, anything up to c++20 is fair game for this question.
(As an aside to the question, I am questioning whether there is much use in trying to provide support basic_string types outside of just string and wstring, given how sparse support for them is in the standard. There is std::cout, and std::wcout, but -- as far as I'm aware -- there is no such equivalent for u8string, u16string, and u32string.)

How much inconvenience would you be willing to tolerate? Would it be OK to have to write e.g. make_literal<char_type>("foo") in place of the current "foo"s? Are your literals limited to ASCII? It shouldn't be hard to write a function taking char* with ASCII characters, and returning basic_string<char_type> (e.g. using basic_string constructor taking a pair of iterators).

Is the only problem you're facing the string literals? So you want to know how to get a String literal that depends on the template type parameter?

First, let's review your approach. For each class (bar, baz, foo, etc), you're coding a function template, which should convert this specific class to a certain kind of basic_string (that is, to a string, a wstring, a u8string, etc), according to the type variable provided to the template.
These function templates will be called from a few specific functions, one per each kind of basic_string. These upper level functions will use an auto parameter, being common for all classes. (Actually, functions using an auto parameter are “abbreviated function templates”, and you'll end up with two nested levels of function templates.)
Anyway, you're facing two (related) problems.

Your core to_basic_string() function templates are supposed to return any kind of basic_string, but they're actually designed to always return "classic" char-based strings (ie. instances of std::basic_string<char>).

More important. There isn't a predefined way of converting between all different classes based on basic_string (or between a "classic" char-based string and a wstring, a u8string, etc).


That's because types like char, wchar_t, or char8_t specify the size of each element in a char[], wchar_t[], char8_t[], etc (or in a string, wstring, u8string, etc), but they don't say anything about the encoding. That is, they don't say anything about which character is represented by a given bit pattern. They don't even say how many elements (and how many bits) are required to represent a single character.
String variants and common encodings
A char[] or a string is composed of "narrow" char elements, whose size is at least 8 bits (in practice, exactly 8 bits, 1 byte). They're usually encoded in some ISO-8859 variant (one character per char/byte), depending on the Unix "locale" or the Windows "codepage". Or, maybe, in UTF-8 (which uses one, two, three or four char (bytes) per character). Or in plain old 7-bit ASCII (which is currently a subset of UTF-8).
A wchar_t[] or wstring is composed of "wide" wchar_t elements, whose size is implementation (usually platform) dependent. On Windows, a wchar_t is 16-bit long, and these strings usually contain characters encoded using UTF-16 (one or two 16-bit wchar_t "units" per character). (In previous versions of Windows, they were encoded in UCS-2, an old restricted form of UTF-16 with exactly one 16-bit wchar_t "unit" per character.) On Linux, a wchar_t is 32-bits long, and these strings are supposed to be encoded using UTF-32 (always one 32-bit unit per character).
Note: the encoding of char/wchar literals in the source code isn't defined by the standard, and it may depend on several things.
A "Unicode ready" char8_t[] or u8string string is composed of char8_t elements (which have the same minimum size of char elements, 8 bits), and it's supposed to be encoded using UTF-8.
A "Unicode ready" char16_t[] or u16string string is composed of char16_t elements (of at least 16 bits), and it's supposed to be encoded using UTF-16.
A "Unicode ready" char32_t[] or u32string string is composed of char32_t elements (of at least 32 bits), and it's supposed to be encoded using UTF-32.
Proposed solution (mostly for the first problem)
For solving the first problem, I would replace the inner level function templates by simple functions (except, partially, for foo) and do something like this:
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std::literals;

// Define the types...

template <std::size_t... Is>
struct foo {};

struct bar {};

struct baz {};

// Define the to_string functions for each class

template<typename std::size_t first, std::size_t... Is>
std::string to_string(foo<first, Is...> arg)
{
    std::stringstream stst;

    stst << "foo<"s << first;

    if (sizeof...(Is) > 0)
    {
        ((stst << ","s << Is), ...);
    }

    stst << ">"s;

    return stst.str();
}

std::string to_string(bar arg)
{
    using namespace std::literals;

    return "bar"s;
}

std::string to_string(baz arg)
{
    using namespace std::literals;

    return std::string{};
}

// Define (for generic argument, which already has a "classic" string representation) functions that convert to the particular basic_string instantiations, such as wstring, u8string, etc.

#include <codecvt>

std::wstring to_wstring(auto arg)
{
  
    // This is just an example, using currently depreciated tools; it should work if the (char) string is UTF-8 encoded (including plain old 7-bit ASCII strings, with the eight bit set to 0)
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
    return converter.from_bytes(to_string(arg));
}

std::u8string to_u8string(auto arg)
{
    return to_string(arg);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << to_string(foo<0, 2, 4, 6, 8>{}) << "\n"s;
    std::cout << to_string(bar{}) << "\n"s;
    std::cout << to_string(baz{}) << "\n"s;

    std::wcout << to_wstring(foo<0, 2, 4, 6, 8>{}) << L"\n"s;
    std::wcout << to_wstring(bar{}) << L"\n"s;
    std::wcout << to_wstring(baz{}) << L"\n"s;
}

As a final note, I would move the inner functions, like to_string(bar arg) inside the specific class, removing the parameter.
Should I support "Unicode ready" strings?
If you don't really need to provide an explicit support for different variants of Unicode, I would answer "no". Current operating systems offer two "character" interfaces (not just for "console" applications, but also for some GUI APIs). One interface using char strings (std::cout, from the C++ point of view of a console application), and another one using wchar_t strings (std::wcout). As been said, the expected encoding for char strings is based on the locale or the codepage; and the expected encoding for wchar_t is OS dependent (see above).

note: templates from <codecvt> are deprecated

I know. This was just an example, which only works for a string encoded as UTF-8 (including those encoded in plain old 7-bit ASCII) and a wstring encoded as UTF-16 (one or more 16-bit "units" per character) (as wide characters are implemented in Windows).

The actual conversion between u8string and u16string should use Unicode specific functions (assuming these strings are really encoded using UTF-8 and UTF-16). The actual conversion from/to wstring will depend on the OS (for Windows, a wstring may be assimilated to a u16string; for Linux, to a u32string). The actual representation of the string literals will depend on several factors.
